# Call the request each time I navigate to that certain screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am fetching the user data through the `fetchUser()` method on the home screen but when I update the income, it is not updated on the home screen when I navigate back. How can I make the method `fetchUser` be called each time I navigate to the home screen?

Or what else I can do so I can achieve this?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:fin_app/apiservice/variables.dart';
import 'package:month_year_picker/month_year_picker.dart';
// import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:fin_app/screens/login_screen/components/overview_screen/top_card.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../models/user.dart';
import '../monthly_expense/expense_app_theme.dart';
import 'input_form.dart';



class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String dropdownValue = list.first;
  List userData = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  
    fetchUser();
  }

  Future<User> fetchUser() async {
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };

    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://10.0.2.2:7014/api/user/me'),
      headers: requestHeaders,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      // income=jsonDecode(response.body)['income'];
      
      income=jsonDecode(response.body)['profile']['income'];
      return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      print(response.statusCode.toString());
      throw Exception('Failed to load user');
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: ExpenseAppTheme.background,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          TopNeuCard(balance: '\ 20,000', expense: '100'),
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.00),
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: dropdownValue,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                    elevation: 100,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 44, 121, 244)),
                    underline: Container(
                      height: 2,
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 44, 121, 244),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (String? value) {
                      // This is called when the user selects an item.
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownValue = value!;
                      });
                      _fetchData();
                    },
                    items: list.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(height: 275, child: _buildListView(context))
              ],
            )),
          )),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: navigate,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 121, 146, 237),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add_rounded),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _fetchData() async {
    var apiUrl2 =
        'https://10.0.2.2:7014/api/expense/me/month?month=2022%20$dropdownValue';

    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };

    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(apiUrl2),
      headers: requestHeaders,
    );
    final data = json.decode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      setState(() {
        userData = data;
      });
    } else if (response.statusCode == 404) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("No expenses present")));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      print(response.statusCode.toString());
      throw Exception('Failed to load expenses');
    }
  }

  Future deletePost(String id) async {
    var apiUrl = 'https://10.0.2.2:7014/api/expense/me/$id';
    // final res = await http.delete(Uri.parse(apiUrl));

    // if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    //   print("Deleted");
    // } else {
    //   throw "Sorry! Unable to delete this post.";
    // }

    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };

    final response = await http.delete(
      Uri.parse(apiUrl),
      headers: requestHeaders,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Deleted succesfully")));
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      print(response.statusCode.toString());
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text("Expense could not be deleted ")));

      throw Exception('Failed to load expenses');
    }
  }

  void navigate() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const FormInput()),
    );
  }

  ListView _buildListView(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: userData.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(
            child: ListTile(
          title: Text(userData[index]["category"]),
          subtitle: Text(userData[index]["date"]),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            color: Colors.red,
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                deletePost(userData[index]["id"]);
                userData.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
          ),
          trailing: Text(
            '-' '\$' + userData[index]["amount"].toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
              //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 16,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          onTap: () {},
        ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
void navigate() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const FormInput()),
    );
  }
```

to this:

```
void navigate() async {
    bool result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const FormInput()),
    );
    if(result != null && result){
       fetchUser();
    }
  }
```

then inside `FormInput`, pop like this:

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

Comment: The form input does not have anything to do with the data I am trying to display

Comment: you want to get user data when come back from FormInput to home page right?